# Mysql - dynamic UNION with multiple recieve ids

Tags: mysql, sql, union

how to convert this multiple UNION  to simple query?

**number of `artist_id` is dynamic.**

- 45,122,95

or

- 100,20

or

- 89,9449

or

- 22,495,700,98

....

```
(SELECT b.`id`, b.`id`, b.`date`, b.`artist`, b.`title`, b.`photo`
FROM `tags_mp3s` a
INNER JOIN `mp3s` b ON b.`id` = a.`mp3_id` AND a.`artist_id` = 45
ORDER BY b.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5)

UNION ALL

(SELECT b.`id`, b.`id`, b.`date`, b.`artist`, b.`title`, b.`photo`
FROM `tags_mp3s` a
INNER JOIN `mp3s` b ON b.`id` = a.`mp3_id` AND a.`artist_id` = 122
ORDER BY b.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5)

UNION ALL

(SELECT b.`id`, b.`id`, b.`date`, b.`artist`, b.`title`, b.`photo`
FROM `tags_mp3s` a
INNER JOIN `mp3s` b ON b.`id` = a.`mp3_id` AND a.`artist_id` = 95
ORDER BY b.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5)

.....
```

thanks

Comment: why dont you use `where in`?

Comment: @farhadamjady because i want  `ORDER BY b.`date` DESC` for each `artist_id`. in `where in()` select all according `id` then i not want.

Comment: ok, you dont want to use server side language? just native sql?

Comment: @farhadamjady i want use server side. in function. PHP mysql: `function getrelated() { ..query and get related rows... }`

Comment: Maybe use combination of IN (as per farhadamjady) and "fake row-over" - see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895110/1662973

Comment: no i mean something like loop for generating the main query then use it, if not you can use for loop in sql

Comment: @farhadamjady how to loop in sql? i can generate this select union. but i find best simple solution

Comment: @farhadamjady you cannot loop in SQL without stored procedure which in some cases didn't work when sending queries just to fetch some data in dynamic condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use variables:

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             (@rn := if(@a = t.artist_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@a := t.artist_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM tags_mp3s t INNER JOIN
           mp3s m
           ON m.id = t.mp3_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @a := -1) params
      WHERE t.artist_id IN (. . . )
      ORDER BY t.artist_id, m.date DESC
     ) ta
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: thanks, tested but, `#1051 - Unknown table 't'` and `Unrecognized keyword. (near "CROSS" at position 278)`

Comment: Gordon Linoff: `ORDER BY m.date DESC` doesnt work. sorted by `t.artist_id`. why?

Comment: @grizzly . . . I don't understand the comment.  There is no `ORDER BY m.date DESC` in the query.

Comment: `m.date DESC` work for after selected rows, and this no need. i want newest rows from `mp3s` table according `date` column. 2017,2016,2015,...... but this query sort rows according first ids. so first ids have oldest date

Comment: `m.date DESC` work for after selected rows, and this no need. i want newest rows from `mp3s` table according `date` column. 2017,2016,2015,....... but this query sort rows according first ids. so first ids have oldest date: 2008,2007,2004,2003,......while 2017,2016,...... are newest tracks

Comment: @grizzly . . . Are you sure that `ORDER BY` is `ORDER BY t.artist_id, m.date DESC`?  The first key has to be the artist.

Comment: yes, `t.artist_id` not important for me. i need select 5 latest new track for each artist according song date. song dates in all of the time.